# Hiding layers and then exporting as jpeg in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I makes timelapse videos from the drawings, for that purpose I use the following photoshop script to export jpeg pictures with one button press on my wacom. Now here's the issue, there are times when I want some specific layers to be hidden while exporting the jpeg pictures. I'm a complete noob in photoshop scripting so I need help in achieving the following.

Hide certain layer. Lets say "Background" layer.
Export jpeg picture as usual.
Turn "background" layer visible again.
Return back to active layer as at the start of this script so I can smoothly keep drawing and exporting the pictures.

```
> #target photoshop;

if (app.documents.length > 0) {
  var thedoc = app.activeDocument;

  var docName = thedoc.name;
  if (docName.indexOf(".") != -1) {
    var basename = docName.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
  } else {
    var basename = docName;
  }

  //getting the location, if unsaved save to desktop;
  try {
    var docPath = thedoc.path;
  } catch (e) {
    var docPath = "~/Desktop";
  }

  var jpegOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  jpegOptions.quality = 9;
  jpegOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  jpegOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;

  var filename = docPath + '/' + basename + "-" + getTime() + '.jpg';

  thedoc.saveAs((new File(filename)), jpegOptions, true);
};

function getTime(){
  var currentTime = new Date();

  //Make single-digit mins show up as 6:01 and not 6:1
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  var timeStamp = currentTime.getFullYear() + "-"
  + (currentTime.getMonth() + 1) + "-"
  + currentTime.getDate() + "-"
  + currentTime.getHours() + "."
  + minutes + "."
  + currentTime.getSeconds() + "."
  + currentTime.getMilliseconds();
  return timeStamp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making an action that Hides the background?

You can record the action including the following steps;
• Hide Background Layer
• Run Script
• Make Background Layer Visible

Then bind it to your wacom.

Hope that helps.